# How to set webpack to rebuild ui on another ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT?

Tags: webpack, visual-studio-2017

I delete appsettings.Development.json file because I need different settings file for remote server. After that webpack not rebuild automatically my app :(. In Visual Studio 2017 I add an environment variable (right click on project -> Properties -> Debug -> select IIS Express Profile -> add environment variable)